# Jacobi modulus and Weierstrass $\wp$

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals

Let $0 < k < 1$ and $$K := \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2(\theta)}} \, \mathrm{d}\theta, \; \; K' := \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - (1-k^2) \sin^2(\theta)}} \, \mathrm{d}\theta.$$

If we form the lattice $L = 4K \mathbb{Z} \oplus 4iK' \mathbb{Z}$ and let $$e_1 = \wp(2K), \; e_2 = \wp(2iK'), \; e_3 = \wp(2K + 2iK')$$ be the values of $\wp(z;L)$ at half-periods, then the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) claims in the last section that $$k^2 = \frac{e_2 - e_3}{e_1 - e_3}.$$ I have seen a similar formula in Markushevich's *Theory of functions of a complex variable* but it defines $k$ and $K$ in a way that makes this obvious (not via an elliptic integral). I don't know how to prove this using the definitions given.

Comment: If you want to set $\tau=\frac{\mathrm{i}K'}{K}$ and $k^2=\lambda(\tau)$ ([elliptic lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function)), then it seems you'll have to swap $e_2$ and $e_3$, resulting in $\lambda=\frac{e_3-e_2}{e_1-e_2}$. Your formula actually gives $\lambda(\tau+1)$. The corresponding lattices are equivalent, so the distinction might be unimportant.